# python keyboard module does error out when using CMD on a mac

Tags: python-3.x

Not sure what is wrong, but when I try to use the Option modifier on a mac, using keyboard module, I get an error

```
keyboard.press_and_release('cmd+option+n')
```

The error:

```
    _os_keyboard.press(scan_codes[0])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

It works fine if I use shift for example, like

```
keyboard.press_and_release('cmd+shift+n')
```

Am I using the wrong modifier key?

EDIT-------------------
After poking in the module and stepping in the function that does the key press and release; I noticed that when passing `alt`, it does not get converted in a numeric code. All other keys and modifiers do get converted in numbers, which is the keycode in ASCII I believe but not `alt` (same for option).

I double checked and the module does have `alt` as key, although it seems that the function that translate the string into a keycode is not able to assign the code, so the tuple end up being empty and the error is triggered.

I will check with the team that makes the library to see if they are aware of the issue; nothing really I can fix unless I modify the module itself.

Comment: I'm not very familar with what you are doing, but isn't the option key also the alt key?

Comment: Yes, on Windows the key is called `alt`, while on OSX is called `option`; the documentation of the `keyboard` module is quite scarce on that aspect

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, the option key is also the alt key.

So maybe you could try:

```py
keyboard.press_and_release("cmd+alt+n")
```

Give that a try and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, same issue using alt instead of Option. Tried also `opt` but I get an error that say that the key opt is not mapped; so I guess `option` is correct, but I don't get why it does error out

Comment: Sadly not, as mentioned in the previous comment I get the same error :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the answer then. It was a simple guess I took, I'm not familiar with the keyboard module.

Comment: @heyjude Try the alt upper case!